# ThinkPad E470 Card Reader not working

Tags: drivers, lenovo, thinkpad, sd-card, firmware

I'm having problems with my SD card reader. I own a Lenovo ThinkPad E470 with Ubuntu 16.04 (fully updated). When inserting the SD card nothing happens, only `dmesg` gives me these lines:

```
[  576.659543] sdhci: Timeout waiting for Buffer Read Ready interrupt during tuning procedure, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  576.659573] mmc0: tuning execution failed
[  576.659596] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
```

My reader is a `02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8621 (rev 01)`.

It's not the card as it is working with other computers. I don't understand why it does not work out of the box as it was certified (https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201609-25122/).

I already found other people having the same problem. It seems to be a kernel problem. Is it necessary to compile my own kernel or is there an easier workaround (I wouldn't receive kernel updates anymore after updating it, would I?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have the Thinkpad E470. The internal card reader can be used using the option `debug_quirks2="0x4000"` for the module `sdhci`. This activates the `SDHCI_QUIRK2_ACMD23_BROKEN` behaviour. You can set this option by adding a file `10-sdhci.conf` to `/etc/modprobe.d` containing

```
options sdhci debug_quirks2="0x4000"  # SDHCI_QUIRK2_ACMD23_BROKEN
```

After that, it may be necessary to rebuild your init ram disk (`update-initramfs -u`) to make sure this option is there when the module is loaded on boot.